# What are the reasons for not deleting the pdf file in server? But in local it works

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is some part of my code..

```
if (fileInfo.Exists) {

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = contentType;
    HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + hdnFileName.Value + "." + extension);

    try {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.WriteFile(hdnReportPath.Value);
        Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        AppException appEx = AppException.Handle(ex, string.Format("Agency:{0} User:{1}", agencyID, userId));
    } finally {

    }

}

if (fileInfo.Exists)    
    File.Delete(hdnReportPath.Value);
```

It does not produce any exception or error, but it is not working in server(IIS), It works good in local. What are the reasons for not deleting the pdf file in server? 
Thanks in advance....

Comment: Does it satisfy the condition `fileInfo.Exists` in server?

Comment: What account is it running under on server? Does that account have sufficient permissions to delete files?

Comment: As @shree.pat18 says, the account used to give access to the IIS server needs to have permits to modify the folders in which you are trying  to write.

Answer (score 1):

check the permission of folder of your application which you host in IIS.
it might be effect while save/delete.

Answer (score 0):

You check the file exists, if it does then you create it. Then check if it exists and delete it if it does...

There seems to be something wrong with your logic here. If the file doesn't exist nothing will ever happen.

Comment: Hi Lee Willis,Already created the file and trying to open that file, after file opening delete the file from the folder. This is the logic